# How to set the default branch in Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I wanted to change the default branch in git repository hosted on Gitlab.

current default is **v0.1**, wanted to change to **master**.

v0.1 was the first branch created in repo on init.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the project settings (link: edit project, depending on the version this is hidden on the upper right behind the sandwich link), there you can change the default branch.

Comment: can't this be set to master by default by the maintainer somehow?

Answer (score 1):

To add onto the answer from @MrTux, it sounds like you don't have a master branch. You'll need to create that before you can edit the default branch.

I think Gitlab likes to follow the idea of only showing things that you can actually change, and since you only have one branch, then it must be the default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on your project
2. Settings (left bar)
3. Repository
4. Default Branch